# strcpy in c is behaving different

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I am trying to understand strcpy() function but I could not. As said in [this page](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-strings/c-strcpy-function/) If destination string length is less than source string, entire source string value won’t be copied into destination string, Instead it will be truncated. But when I tried to run this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char my_full_name[]="TomCruse_MI";
    char my_school_name[]="DON_BOSCO";
    strcpy(my_school_name, my_full_name);
    printf("After strcpy() function to copy my name into my school : \'%s\'\n" , my_school_name);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the out as :

```
After strcpy() function to copy my name into my school : 'TomCruse_MI'
```

My question is how come the string 'TomCruse_MI' is not getting truncated even though the source string is larger than the destination size.

Comment: undefined behaviour. You broke something but you'll know it later in your program. Or it'll work.

Comment: Behaving different---Undefined behavior

Comment: `my_school_nane` is not big enough !

Comment: That site you linked is **fundamentally wrong**. There will be no truncation etc. (since the function *cannot* know the destination buffer's size), asking to copy more characters than the buffer can hold is simply Undefined Behaviour (a buffer overrun), plain and simple.

Comment: that site is appalling indeed. Note that the example given uses a _bigger_ destination size so it works... Don't believe everything on the internet. Read StackOverflow :)

Comment: Wow I am also appalled by the site linked.  Here is a better link for you to use.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html

Comment: Bah.. another "programming" site for a blacklist...

Comment: Even if you don't know anything about C, the `Copyright 2018 ©  http://localhost/fresh2refresh` footer should send you off screaming...

Comment: My goodness, who runs that site?

Comment: Some Java enthusiasts?

Comment: note: `TomCruse_MI` should be `TomCruise_MI` (effect of the truncation already?)